# Unity Export Package Taking Too Long

Tags: unity

I'm trying to export a Unity Package and it's taking far too long (it just keeps counting, and doesn't end). I'm not sure why it continues to count in the `PackageImporter.Tick` but I'm wondering if others have noticed performance issues.

Unity Version: 2020.2.3f1
OS: Windows 10

Comment: Can you build your project without issues?

Comment: Can you tell us anything about what's in the package that you're exporting? If you make a new Unity project with just one or two assets in it, and export that as a package, do you get the same problem?

Comment: Actually, I found it was an issue with 2020.2.3f1. I've upgraded to 2020.2.6f1 and I have no issues exporting at all now.

Thank you for following up here~

Answer (score 1):

[Following this thread from Unity Forums](https://forum.unity.com/threads/lots-of-busy-hold-on-etc.833644/) I came to a conclusion to update, I no longer have the issue I was facing with the `ImportPackage.Tick()` hanging the editor